# Casting this pointer to derived class in CRTP

Tags: c++, crtp

I wonder if this code is well defined. Seems to me fine, but hopefully someone can explain this (either correct, or wrong) in standard terms.

```
template <typename T>
class B {
public:
    B (int n) : p {n} {}

    T& operator++ () {
        ++p;
        return static_cast<T&> (*this); // (X)
    }

    int p;
};

class Z : public B<Z> {
public:
    using B::B;
    int boo = 42;
};
```

and usage:

```
Z z {10};
std::cout << z.p << " " << z.boo << "\n";
Z& x = ++z;
std::cout << x.p << " " << x.boo << "\n";
x.boo = 1;
++x;
std::cout << z.p << " " << z.boo << "\n";
```

What people always do is to have a reference to the base class and pass the derived object to it. Here I have the opposite behavior in (X). Output of usage is as expected. I am asking if extension of Z can cause a problem?

Comment: Extension of `Z` can indeed be a problem if you expect `operator++` to return something other than `Z&`.

Comment: In fact I want B template to be used only as a base class for new types like Z.

Comment: Then your question is very unclear.

Comment: B is for having some common operations for new types, lets say there is B::operator+(T). You create new type like Z and having two objects of Z (z1, z2) you can add them. Implementation of operator+(T) is stored only in B but z1+z2 is ok (just like the operator would be defined in Z). Overloading operator+(T) is easier since return type (I know for UDT can be even void) is T, but for operator++() should be T&. I didn't want to explain exact idea here since I thought its not important.